# Mysql select box with jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-selectbox

i have a country state city database that displaying in select boxes and everything is working fine. What i want when state select box selected to display city results in a div or another element. When select box defined for city results there is no problem but if i use div gives the error message

> Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\wamp\www\list\post.php on line 3.

here is my codes, thanks.

**post.php**

```
include("connect.php");
$country = $_POST['country'];
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from state where country_id='$country'");

while( $list = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
    echo '<option value=' . $list["id"]. '>' . $list["state_name"] . '</option>';
}

 $state = $_POST['state'];
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from city where state_id='$state'");

while( $list = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
    echo $list["city_name"];
}
```

**jquery** codes

```
$( "#countries" ).change( function(){
    $("#states").empty();
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.post("post.php", {country:val}, function(a) {
        $("#states").append(a);
        });
});

$( "#states" ).change( function(){
    $("#cities").empty();
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.post("post.php", {state:val}, function(a) {
        $("#cities").append(a);
        });
});
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include("connect.php"); ?>
<select id="countries">
<option>select</option>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connect, 'select * from country');
while( $list = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
    echo '<option value=' . $list["id"]. '>' . $list["country_name"] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>

<select id="states">
<option>select</option>
</select>

<div id="cities"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to cheeck whether it was called with the `country` or `state` parameter, and perform the appropriate query. And the code for returning the cities needs to put them in `<option>`, just like returning states does.

```
include("connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['country']);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from state where country_id='$country'");

    while( $list = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
        echo '<option value=' . $list["id"]. '>' . $list["state_name"] . '</option>';
    }
elseif (isset($_POST['state'])) {

    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['state']);
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from city where state_id='$state'");

    while( $list = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
        '<option value=' . $list["id"]. '>' . $list["city_name"] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

You should also learn to use parametrized queries instead of substituting variables, to prevent SQL injection. Until then, you should at least escape the parameters.